# while importing torch- shows - [WinError 126] The specified module could not be found

Tags: python, pytorch

I have tried to install python torch by using

```
  !pip install torch
```

But I got the error **OSError: [WinError 126] The specified module could not be found**

Then I tried with

```
pip install torch -f https://download.pytorch.org/whl/torch_stable.html
```

The running log is as follows,

[image]

Then I have installed the torch by the below command to install the CPU version of the torch.

```
pip install torch==1.7.1+cpu torchvision==0.8.2+cpu torchaudio===0.7.2 -f https://download.pytorch.org/whl/torch_stable.html
```

Then, when I try to test by the command,

```
import torch
print(torch.__version__)
```

In the Spyder, it still could not recognize,
[image]

However, in python.exe it could recognize and provides the correct output.

[image]

Comment: does your computer have a CUDA enabled gpu?

Comment: I do not think I have CUDA enabled GPU since my machine has RADEON VEGA 3 Graphics which is not NVIDIA.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok the problem is that you are trying to install the cuda version of Pytorch on a non cuda enabled computer. You can find a similar problem [here](https://discuss.pytorch.org/t/cannot-import-torch-on-jupyter-notebook/79334). You have to download the cpu version of pytorch like this

```
pip install torch==1.7.1+cpu torchvision==0.8.2+cpu torchaudio===0.7.2 -f https://download.pytorch.org/whl/torch_stable.html
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for your reply. I have updated the post after implementing the solution. Please have a look if you can. Now, in short, from Spyder, it could not recognize but from Python.exe it could recognize.

Comment: Is your spyder in a conda environment? Because then you would need to use conda to install it.